# Modifying oozie code

Tags: hadoop, oozie, job-scheduling

I would like to modify the Oozie code to introduce a new scheduling pattern in Hadoop. I am new to Oozie. I read that there is a file called workflow.xml which has the actions that are to be performed by Hadoop. I want to introduce a new field to the job, something like a JOB_TYPE. For eg, if a job belongs to TYPE_1, then it should be replicated in all the worker nodes. If a job belongs to TYPE_2, then it should be replicated in only a fraction of nodes. Is it possible to modify the parser of Oozie which parses the workflow.xml? Please do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie can be used for scheduling tasks, but it is not actually used for such a purpose as specified in the question. Oozie is not aware of the cluster structure of Hadoop. Oozie just provides an opportunity to perform packaging tasks or it can even be used for recurring tasks. Oozie just passes the set of tasks to Hadoop. Hadoop performs the scheduling.